# Firefox does not redirect to correct page

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, firefox

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and Firefox 3.6.3. If I type wrong URL like youtube, it won't redirect me to the correct site. Instead the address would be jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox-3.6.3/chrome/en-US.jar!/locale/browser-region/region.propertiesyoutube and Firefox can't find any page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't "comment" yet so posting this as a suppliment to evowinds post in which he is asking you to modify the firefox configuration file. Here are the instructions on how to make edits:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config

Basically he is asking you to:

1. Open firefox
2. In the URL bar type in "about:config" where you would normally put something like http://www.superuser.com
3. Find the key value CT1896539.SearchFromAddressBarUrl
4. Change the value for this key to TRUE.

Comment: At last, someone has understood me :D Thanks for expansion.

Comment: Bu you got the points huh:)

Comment: Yup and now I can upvote posts to so i gave you credit where it was due :D

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu made a search engine deal with Yahoo in 10.4 LTS release. Of course some settings may be changed.

In about:config page;
CT1896539.SearchFromAddressBarIsInit value is True or False?
If "False", then change it to "True" maybe it helps.
Also then try below.
CT1896539.SearchFromAddressBarUrl;http://search.conduit.com/ResultsExt.aspx?ctid=CT1896539&SearchSource=2&q=

Comment: The value is true and I FF can find the site http://search.conduit.com/ResultsExt.aspx?ctid=CT1896539&SearchSource=2&q= . However, CT1896539.SearchFromAddressBarUrl;http://search.conduit.com/ResultsExt.aspx?ctid=CT1896539&SearchSource=2&q= says that the URL is not valid and can't be loaded.

Comment: how you tried this and got the error message?

Comment: I copypasted that link to the address bar and pressed enter.

Comment: No, no...This link is not a real link. It is also "about:config" setting. "CT1896539.SearchFromAddressBarUrl" is the key and "http://search.conduit.com/ResultsExt.aspx?ctid=CT1896539&SearchSource=2&q=" is the value, OK?

Comment: This gives a Google-like search engine without error messages.